# Code produces ERROR 1064 (42000) and I'm not sure why

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the code:

```
    CREATE TABLE entries (
    entry_id INT NOT NULL,
    date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
    student_id INT,
    subject_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(entry_id)
    FOREIGN KEY student_id REFERENCES students (student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY subject_id REFERENCES subjects (subject_id));
```

The error message returned is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY student_id REFERENCES students
>   (student_id), FOREIGN KEY subject_id ' at line 7

I have thoroughly checked the code and online but I can't seem to find a solution.
Please help

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL? Additionally should there be a comma after  PRIMARY KEY(entry_id)?

Comment: @DB101 It's MySQL and I tried putting the comma in and it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try below

See the Reference
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

```
CREATE TABLE entries (
    entry_id INT NOT NULL,
    date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
    student_id INT,
    subject_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(entry_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects (subject_id));
```